# Changing the owner of a read-only database which is configured with Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, log-shipping

Is there a way to change the owner of a read-only database which is configured with Log Shipping without actually re setting up LS?

Per [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/00fcb65a-9076-4404-b748-8badc508d06d/how-to-change-owner-of-readonly-database-which-is-configured-with-logshipping?forum=transactsql) it's not, but I'm checking if anything has changed since then.

Comment: Changing the owner means changing the database which means writing to the log, so no, the rule is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "without re setting up LS", are you able to have an outage to fix this?

If so, then look at using tail-log backups and recovering the secondary database to make this change. The high-level process would be:

1. Stop LSBackup, LSCopy and LSRestore (after ensuring there are no pending copies or restores)
2. Perform a tail-log backup. The primary DB will now be in recovery and inaccessible
3. Restore the tail-log backup on the secondary and recover the database. It will now be online.
4. Change the database owner as required.
5. Perform a tail-log backup on the secondary. It will now be in recovery and unavailable.
6. Restore the tail-log to the primary and recover it.
7. Re-enable your log shipping jobs and manually execute LSBackup, LSCopy and LSRestore

After this, your primary should be back online and your secondary back in a read-only state. As stated, this will cause an outage on your primary but this may be preferable to reinitialising log shipping on a large DB. Also, make sure you test this process in a non-Production environment first, and have the entire process scripted. SQLCMD mode is a great way to run this as you can script the whole process and run from a single script using the CONNECT option to change between your primary and secondary machine.

[Tail-Log Backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/tail-log-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

[SSMS in SQLCMD Mode](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2311/using-the-ssms-query-editor-in-sqlcmd-mode/)

Comment: I will mark this answer but since cannot have any outage we will move with setting up LS again, thanks for the idea though

Comment: The owner in DB properties will be the user who performed the restore, and fixing requires running sp_changedbowner, which requires bringing the DB online. Since this will break log shipping on the secondary, you may need to look at running the restore as SA, either by logging in as SA or running the restore with EXECUTE AS LOGIN.